# SQL How to optimize insert to table from temporary table

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, optimization, sql-execution-plan

I created procedure where dynamically collecting from various projects (Databases) some records into temporary table and from that temporary table I am inserting into table. With `WHERE` statement , but unfortunately when I checked with Execution plan I find out, that this query part take a lot of load. How can I optimize this `INSERT` part or `WHERE` statement ?

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PROJECTS_TESTS ( PROJECTID, ANOTHERTID, DOMAINID, is_test)
    SELECT * FROM #temp_Test AS tC
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 
                        FROM dbo.PROJECTS_TESTS AS ps WITH (NOLOCK)
                        WHERE ps.PROJECTID = tC.projectId 
                        AND ps.ANOTHERTID = tC.anotherLink 
                        AND ps.DOMAINID = tC.DOMAINID 
                        AND ps.is_test = tC.test_project 
                        )
```

Comment: If this is a production environment then don't use (NOLOCK). Please show the execution plan and why you believe this query to be non-performant. Do you have any indexes on your table PROJECTS_TESTS?

Comment: 1. Create index on #temp projectId, anotherLink, DOMAINID, test_project.    2. Not need @TOP 1 1@ 3.Delete NOLOCK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd be better served by doing a `JOIN` than `EXISTS`.  Depending on the cardinality of your join condition (currently in your `WHERE`) you might need `DISTINCT` in there too.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.PROJECTS_TESTS ( PROJECTID, ANOTHERTID, DOMAINID, is_test)
    SELECT <maybe distinct> tC.* FROM #temp_Test AS tC
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  FROM dbo.PROJECTS_TESTS AS ps on
                        ps.PROJECTID = tC.projectId 
                        AND ps.ANOTHERTID = tC.anotherLink 
                        AND ps.DOMAINID = tC.DOMAINID 
                        AND ps.is_test = tC.test_project 

where ps.PROJECT ID IS NULL
```

or something like that